# Accessing URL through public ip address

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I made configuration of **APACHE + TOMCAT integration** ...

I can access the ***urls*** from **localhost &  public IP address**  as

**case 1:**

*localhost:8180/examples/jsp/*-- **WORKING**

*publicipaddress:81/examples/jsp/*----**WORKING**

But  these URLs are already existed in tomcat (as example-)

*when I deploy new war file on tomcat...... i can access by localhost BUT not through public IP address*

**case 2:**

*localhost:8180/webservices/webapi/myresource*---- **WORKING**

*publicipaddress:81/webservices/webapi/myresource* ----- **NOT WORKING**

**In case 1 both urls working ..but not in case 2**

can anyone help me where i am going wrong ... I am deploying restful web service

Comment: Why do you have different ports?

Comment: i donot have much idea .. but may be due to NAT

Comment: Are you sure you are not running 2 difference services on the same server? Ckeck `/conf/server.xml` to verify. You may have a different application for each service.

Comment: No A. Wabbi ... i am getting error message in web browser saying  **The requested URL /webservices/webapi/myresource was not found on this server.**